# Next.js external component library using Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering, postcss

**Background**
Need to create an external React component library using existing components from a Next.js site, using `Tailwindcss@^2`. This needs to be pulled in using npm, onto any site that requires the components.

**Problem**
I've managed to create the package using `Webpack@^5` to compile. This is all fine, but the problem I face is that, the components don't work when reintroduced to the initial site. I have a feeling this is either the compiling is wrong or the fact that Next.js is server side rendered, or it could be both.

**Attempted solution**
I have tried to use Rollup as an alternate solution to compile the components, but I keep running into an issue with Postcss. A common issue I've noticed, where it's asking for v8 of PostCss (which it appears is present in `node_modules`), but it still complains. I did have a similar issue when using Webpack, but was eventually able to fix this. I've tried similar methods to fix for Rollup, but no luck.

***package.json***

```json
{
  "name": "@github_account/package_name",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum",
  "author": "github_account",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "repo_name_here"
  },
  "main": "./build/main.cjs.js",
  "module": "./build/main.esm.js",
  "browser": "./build/main.js",
  "source": "./src/index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/github_account"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-rollup": "rollup -c",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "iframe-resizer-react": "^1.1.0",
    "luxon": "^2.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.8.4",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.7",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-markdown": "^6.0.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.4",
    "react-select": "^5.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "sass": "^1.42.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^22.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "@squoosh/lib": "^0.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "~9",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.3",
    "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "next-seo": "^4.28.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "8.4.6",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "rollup": "^2.77.0",
    "rollup-plugin-filesize": "^9.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-image": "^1.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-tailwindcss": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.6",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

***webpack.config.js***

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const stylesHandler = MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader;

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  externals: [nodeExternals({ importType: "umd" })],
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: {
      name: "cruil",
      type: "umd",
    },
    assetModuleFilename: (pathData) => {
      const filepath = path.dirname(pathData.filename).split("/").slice(1).join("/");
      return `${filepath}/[name].[hash][ext][query]`;
    },
    globalObject: "this",
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    minimizer: [
      "...",
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        minimizer: {
          implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.squooshMinify,
          options: {
            encodeOptions: {
              pngquant: {
                quality: 90,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
            // or node_modules/packageName
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
            return `npm.${packageName.replace("@", "")}`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$|jsx/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [stylesHandler, "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets"),
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

***rollup.config.js***

```js
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import filesize from "rollup-plugin-filesize";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
import image from "rollup-plugin-image";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import replace from "rollup-plugin-replace";
import tailwind from "rollup-plugin-tailwindcss";

import pkg from "./package.json";

const INPUT_FILE_PATH = "src/index.js";
const OUTPUT_NAME = "main";

const GLOBALS = {
  react: "React",
  "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
  "prop-types": "PropTypes",
};

const getBabelOptions = ({ useESModules }) => ({
  babelrc: false,
  exclude: "node_modules/**",
  extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx"],
  babelHelpers: "runtime",
  presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { modules: false }], "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: [["@babel/transform-runtime", { regenerator: false, useESModules }], "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"],
});

const PLUGINS = [
  external({
    includeDependencies: true,
  }),
  image(),
  tailwind({
    input: "./src/styles/index.css",
    purge: false,
  }),
  postcss({
    extract: true,
    modules: true,
    plugins: [autoprefixer],
  }),
  resolve({
    browser: true,
    resolveOnly: [/^(?!react$)/, /^(?!react-dom$)/, /^(?!prop-types)/],
    preferBuiltins: false,
  }),
  commonjs({
    include: /node_modules/,
  }),
  replace({ "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) }),
  babel(getBabelOptions({ useESModules: true })),
  filesize(),
];

const EXTERNAL = ["react", "react-dom", "prop-types"];

// https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel#babelhelpers
const CJS_AND_ES_EXTERNALS = EXTERNAL.concat(/@babel\/runtime/);

const OUTPUT_DATA = [
  {
    file: pkg.browser,
    format: "umd",
  },
  {
    file: pkg.main,
    format: "cjs",
  },
  {
    file: pkg.module,
    format: "es",
  },
];

const config = OUTPUT_DATA.map(({ file, format }) => ({
  input: INPUT_FILE_PATH,
  output: {
    file,
    format,
    name: OUTPUT_NAME,
    globals: GLOBALS,
  },
  external: ["cjs", "es"].includes(format) ? CJS_AND_ES_EXTERNALS : EXTERNAL,
  plugins: PLUGINS,
}));

export default config;
```

***postcss.config.js***

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-import"),
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
    require("postcss-nesting"),
    require("postcss-custom-properties"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
  ],
};
```

***index.js***

```js
import "./styles/index.css";
import ExampleTestComponent from "./components/ExampleTestComponent";
...

export { 
   ExampleTestComponent,
   ...
}
```

***ExampleTestComponent.js***

```js
import React from "react";

const ExampleTestComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="ExampleTestComponentClass">
      --- This is a test ---
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExampleTestComponent;
```

***index.css***

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

***Site Implementation***

```js
import ExampleTestComponent from "@github_account/package_name";

const HomePageTemplate = ({ heroItems, partners, newsItems, videos }) => {
  const partnerItems = partners.map((partner) => ({
    image: partner.logo,
    url: partner.url,
  }));
  return (
    <HomePageLayout heroItems={heroItems} partnerItems={partnerItems}>

      <ExampleTestComponent />

      <SuccessStoriesSlider videos={videos} />
      <NewsBlock
        newsItems={newsItems}
        title="News"
        subtitle="Latest news posts"
        viewMoreBtnLabel="View Posts"
        readMoreBtnLabel="Read More"
      />
    </HomePageLayout>
  );
};

export default HomePageTemplate;
```

**UPDATE 1**

Turns out a combination of using Yarn and adding the below

```json
{
   "resolutions": {
      "postcss": "8"
   }
}
```

to package.json, fixes the Postcss issue. So now I have the package created, I am attempting to import into the main site. However I'm now getting the error:

```bash
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /node_modules/@github_account/package_name/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /node_modules/@github_account/package_name/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js from /node_modules/@github_account/package_name/build/main.cjs.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename defineProperty.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /node_modules/@github_account/package_name/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/package.json.
```

Comment: Are these files for your component library? Or for your site?

Comment: All files for the component library apart from the last snippet (site implementation).

Comment: A quick update. So I've retried using yarn instead and then adding:

`{"resolutions": {"postcss": "8"}}` to my package.json,

and that seems to have resolved the postcss issue. Going to see if I can get the rest of it compiled now and back into the site. Will update with my progress.

Comment: is your library generating a `css` file? And are you importing it into your site implementation, either in the HTML's  `<head/>` or as `import "./styles/index.css";` in your `index.js`?

Comment: It's added as an import in my index.js (see index.js code above).